# How do I make the beginning part of UILabel cut off if text is too long?

Tags: swift, text, uilabel, cut

So in `UILabel` , when the text is too log, the label shows the text like

> "This is the te..."

However, I want to add an important information at the end and show it like

> "...is the text end"

Is there any way to set this up programmatically in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to truncate the heading of text

```
lbl.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingHead
```

**byTruncatingHead**

> The line is displayed so that the end fits in the container and the missing text at the beginning of the line is indicated by an ellipsis glyph. Although this mode works for multiline text, it is more often used for single line text.

See other [Options](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslinebreakmode)